# How do I determine if a VSLangProj.Reference is a Project Reference or a File Reference?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-addins

I am working on a Visual Studio plug-in. Given a VSLangProj.Reference, is there a way to programmatically determine if that reference is a project reference or a file reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in [VS 2008 the Reference Type has a property called SourceProject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vslangproj.reference.sourceproject%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

*Gets a Project object if the reference is a project. Otherwise, it returns Nothing (a null reference). Read-only.*

Comment: I was sure that I tried that and it didn't give the proper results. But at your prompting I tried it again and it seems to be working properly after all. Thanks!

Comment: A project (e.g. a .csproj) could have a ProjectReference but that project is not part of the solution in which case the **SourceProject** is null. Is there any other way to find out if this is coming from a "Reference" or "ProjectReference" without parsing through the csproj?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've got so far:

```
if (reference.Type == prjReferenceType.prjReferenceTypeActiveX)
{
    // reference is a COM object
}
else if (reference.SourceProject != null)
{
    // reference is a project in the solution
}
else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reference.Path))
{
    // "reference" is either
    // an valid external dll
    // or a project that is not in the solution and is referenced by a C++ project
}
else
{
    // reference is either
    // a project not in the solution
    // or an external dll with invalid path
}
```